# Prevent redrawn in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm working on Windows Phone8 and have somes problems with performance. I have a grid with 2 lines, the first one is LongListSelector and the second one is Textbox. When i turn on Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableRedrawRegions = true, my textbox was redrawn time after time(i just focus on it, don't typy any thing). But if i remove or collapse LongListSelector it become regular(don't lag).

Any suggesions for me?
Thanks in adnvance.

Comment: Can you please share what you have done. Do you have code? Xaml?

Comment: You can see below:`<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <StackPanel>
                <phone:LongListSelector />
                <TextBox x:Name="txtMessage"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>`

Comment: If you dont want textbox to be redrwn try settign CacheMode="BitmapCache" on it..